# How do not Allow user to toggle master View from specific view

Tags: swift, uisplitviewcontroller

In split view, How do not Allow user to toggle master View from specific view  ?

I want the master to be always hidden even user try to dragging

Comment: With the mentioned description of what the question is, I assume you will be unable to get a useful answer, could you elaborate?

Comment: @AhmadF simply I want to make master unreachable to user even him try to dragging master from details view